# SCons: How can I create a link to another repository's target if the target is built in the other repository

Tags: python, build-process, build, build-automation, scons

When I add a `Repository` to a `SConstruct` file ([link](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c3810.html#AEN3814)), if any target in my repository has been built in this other repository (and the dependencies haven't changed), then `SCons` will *not* build the target -- which is really cool. Unfortunately, I have some tools which rely on the targets being placed in a certain location.  How can I create a link in my current repository to this other repository's target when `SCons` decides to not build locally because the other repository already has the target built?

**EDIT:**
It looks like `SCons` has a 'Local' function which will copy a file from the other repository to the local repository ([link](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x3986.html)).  What I really need is a soft-link, because these targets are big and there is a lot of redundancy.

Comment: Is this on windows or non-windows? Which version of SCons?

Comment: It was in linux and the version of Scons was 2009 version.  I don't remember the resolution.